# Using the Code Below which works I need to add another function that only moves the data in Cell A and an entire row if a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using the Code Below which works I need to add another function that does everything the else if statement does but rather then moving the entire row of data to another sheet I only need to move data from cell A.

I also need to add a function that will move the entire row of data if a checkbox is checked.

```
function onEdit(e) { 
      if (e.value === 'COMPLETED FAB') {
        var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
        if (sheet.getSheetName() == 'Fabrication') {                     
          logSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Fabrication Completed');    
          var row = e.range.getRow(); 
          var lastRow = logSheet.getLastRow();
          var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()); 
          range.copyTo(logSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1));
          sheet.deleteRow(row);

        }
      }

      else if (e.value === 'FINISHED') {
        var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
        if (sheet.getSheetName() == 'Service') {                     
          logSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Service Completed');   
          var row = e.range.getRow(); 
          var lastRow = logSheet.getLastRow();
          var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()); 
          range.copyTo(logSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1));
          sheet.deleteRow(row);

        }
      }

      else if (e.value === 'SURV COMP') {
        var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
        if (sheet.getSheetName() == 'Surveys') {                     
          logSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Surveys Completed');    
          var row = e.range.getRow(); 
          var lastRow = logSheet.getLastRow();
          var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()); 
          range.copyTo(logSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1));
          sheet.deleteRow(row);

        }
      }

    }
```

Comment: Is there a specific problem in achieving your goal?

Comment: The problem is that if I try to add (2) more else if statements the code does not work on the next 2 else if statements. Also the problem with the if statement is that I need the data to go to the next available Cell A because if there is data in Cell A then the data on that sheet will not transfer

Comment: Try `switch...case` instead of `if...else`?

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish your goal you can substitute the [`if…else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) logic with a [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) scenario. The end result look similar to this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  switch (e.value) {
    case 'COMPLETED FAB':
      var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
      if (sheet.getSheetName() == 'Fabrication') {
        logSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Fabrication Completed');
        var row = e.range.getRow();
        var lastRow = logSheet.getLastRow();
        var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
        range.copyTo(logSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1));
        sheet.deleteRow(row);
      }
      break;
    case 'FINISHED':
      var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
      if (sheet.getSheetName() == 'Service') {
        logSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Service Completed');
        var row = e.range.getRow();
        var lastRow = logSheet.getLastRow();
        var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
        range.copyTo(logSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1));
        sheet.deleteRow(row);
      }
      break;
    case 'SURV COMP': {
      var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
      if (sheet.getSheetName() == 'Surveys') {
        logSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Surveys Completed');
        var row = e.range.getRow();
        var lastRow = logSheet.getLastRow();
        var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
        range.copyTo(logSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1));
        sheet.deleteRow(row);
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

The previous code will work as your original one, but don't hesitate to comment on my answer for any doubt.

Comment: I am now receiving the Syntax Error: Unexpected token case (line 36, file "Code.gs")

Comment: That error reports a bad syntax on line 36. Looking back on my code, the line 36 doesn't have any syntax error (it is just a `}`). It seems that you have other pieces of code around, so the line number 36 in your code is different from the line 36 in my answer. Could you please share the line 36 in your code so we all can take a look?